# Why is a certain projective limit of weighted symmetric Fock space, namely $\bigcap\limits_{\tau \in T, p\ge 1 } \mathcal{F}(H_\tau,p)$, separable

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

I have a question regarding separability of a certain locally convex space.

Let $H_{\tau}:=H^{\tau_1}(\mathbb{R}^n,\tau_2(x)dx)$ the weighted Sobolev Hilbert space with $\tau_1 \in \mathbb{N}, \tau_2(x)\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and with $\tau_2 \ge 1$.

We denote $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\bigcap_\tau H_\tau$, when $\tau$ is arbitrary with stated properties above (and call $T$ the index set of all these $\tau$), endowed with the projective topology with respect to all the embeddings $\iota_\tau: \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n) \longrightarrow H_\tau$, i.e. the coarsest topology for which all these embeddings are continuous. This space is a nuclear and separable. The folowing construction will be the case, when $n=1$.

Also consider the symmetrical Fock spaces

$$\mathcal{F}(H_\tau):=\bigoplus^\infty_{n=0}H_{\tau, \mathbb{C}}^{\hat \otimes n}$$

of nth-symmetrized Hilbert space tensor products of the Sobolev spaces introduced above. This is the direct sum in of a countable collection of Hilbert spaces. We now consider the weighted Fock spaces

$$\mathcal{F}(H_\tau,p)=\lbrace (f_n) \in \mathcal{F}(H_\tau):\sum_n \|f_n\|^2_{H_{\tau,\mathbb{C}}^{\hat \otimes n}}\cdot p_n < \infty \rbrace,$$

for sequences $(p_n)$ with $p_n\ge 1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

The space I am interested in is

$$\mathcal{F}_{\text{fin}}(\mathcal{D})=\bigcap\limits_{\tau \in T, p\ge 1 } \mathcal{F}(H_\tau,p)$$

the locally convex space as the projective limit of the weighted Fock spaces endowed with the projective topology, i.e. the initial topology with respect to all the embeddings $\iota_{\tau, p}:\mathcal{F}_{\text{fin}}(\mathcal{D}) \longrightarrow \mathcal{F}(H_\tau,p)$. I am wondering why this space is separable..

The separability is necessary to apply the so called projection spectral theorem in its most general form see [Y.M. Berezansky et al. Spectral Methods in Infinite-Dimensional Analysis, Chapter 3, Theorem 2.7]. This space gets used in the paper [Yu. M. Berezansky and V. A. Tesko. “The investigation of Bogoliubov func-
tionals by operator methods of moment problem”. In: Methods Funct. Anal.
Topology 22.1 (2016), pp. 1–47. issn: 1029-3531] as if it is separable, but the author does not specify why this is the case.

---

My current thoughts lead to the following:

If I can show, that

$$\bigcap_{\tau \in T}(H^{\tau_1}(\mathbb{R},\tau_2(x)dx))^{\otimes n}=\bigcap_{\tau \in T}H^{\tau_1}(\mathbb{R}^n,\tau_2^{\otimes n}(x)dx)=\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n),$$

then $\mathcal{F}_{\text{fin}}(\mathcal{D})=\bigoplus_k \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^k)_{\text{symm},\mathbb{C}}$ as a set, i.e. the set of finite sequences. And since $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^k)$ is separable for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we can conclude
$$\bigoplus_k \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^k)_{\text{symm},\mathbb{C}}$$
is separable as a topological sum. Now If we additionally show that the topology of the sum is finer, than the topology of the projective limit, we are done.

Comment: Your approach seems fine. Lc topology of the sum is the finest among lc topologies with continuous maps to components (universal property). Tensor product of $L^2$ Hilbert spaces are $L^2$ Hilbert spaces over product of spaces. $p_n$ and $\tau_2$ eliminate infinite sequences in direct product and functions with non-compact support. $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}) = \bigcap_{s\in \mathbb{N}} H^{s}_{\mathrm{comp\:  supp}}(\mathbb{R})$ where left hand side (test functions) has finer topology than the right. See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154595/is-the-space-of-test-functions-separable

Comment: The tensor product of Sobolev spaces is not the Sobolev space over product space.. there has to be some inclusion property tho, see my lower approach. I am not entirely sure how the inclusion precisesly looks tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essential is the definition of weighted Sobolev space $H_\tau = H^{\tau_1}(\mathbb{R}, \tau_2)$ as
the completion of $\mathscr{C}^\infty_0$ with respect to the following norm:
$$
    u \mapsto \left\| u \right\|^2_{\tau_1, \tau_2} = \sum_{|\alpha| \le \tau_1}\int \tau_2
    \partial^\alpha u(x)\overline{\partial^\alpha u(x)}\: dx
  $$
Where $\mathscr{C}^\infty_0$ is the space of real-valued infinitely differentiable functions with
compact support. $\mathscr{C}^\infty_0$ is given inductive topology.  $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ is
the same space with projective topology.  Both topologies are nuclear although.
$\left\| \cdot \right\|_{\tau_1, \tau_2}$ norm is continuous for topology of
$\mathscr{C}^\infty_0.$

It is not evident from the beginning that other definitions of weighted Sobolev spaces guarantees
density of $\mathscr{C}^\infty_0.$ Common proof for unweighted case needs Holder-type equality for
convolution (to apply mollification) that cannot be generalized to weighted case in a straight
forward case. For the case of bounded regions, it is definitely true that $\mathscr{C}^\infty_0$
are not dense in any (even unweighted) Sobolev space: compare $\mathcal{H}$ vs. $\mathcal{H}_0.$

To prove separability of $\bigcap\limits_{\tau \in T, p\ge 1 } \mathcal{F}(H_\tau,p),$ it is
sufficient to note that the map
$$
    \otimes^n\mathscr{C}^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathscr{C}^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^n)\to \otimes^n
    \mathcal{H}^{\tau_1}(\mathbb{R}, \tau_2)
  $$
is continuous with dense image for any $\tau = (\tau_1, \tau_2).$
It is by definition for $n=1$ and by the general result: "if $H' \subset H$ is linear dense
subspace of Hilbert space $H$ then $H'\otimes H'$ is dense in $H\widehat{\otimes }H$ and thus in
$H \otimes H.$"

$$
    \otimes^n\mathscr{C}^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathscr{C}^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^n) \to
    \otimes_{sym}^n \mathcal{H}_\tau
  $$
is continuous with dense image, because symmetrization is continuous map (projection).
$$
    \oplus^{lc}_n\otimes^n\mathscr{C}^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}) \to \oplus^{lc}_n\otimes_{sym}^n
    \mathcal{H}_\tau
  $$
is continuous by universal property of sum applied to
$\oplus^{lc}_n\otimes^n\mathscr{C}^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}).$ Topology of $\oplus^{lc}_n$ is that of
inductive limit (final topology). Neighborhoods of 0 of $\oplus^{lc}$ have base, which are convex
hulls $\Gamma(\oplus_n V_n)$ of sets of symmetric convex neighborhoods $V_n$ of 0 in each
component $\otimes_{sym}^n \mathcal{H}_\tau.$

The image of the last map is dense. Take $(v_n)\in \oplus^{lc}_n\otimes_{sym}^n \mathcal{H}_\tau.$
It has finite-number of non-zero components, assume they have indices $ \le N.$ Neighborhood of
$(v_n)$ is $(v_n) + U$ where $U$ is $\Gamma(\oplus_n V_n).$ Approximate $v_n, n \le N$ in $v_n +
  V_n$ with $d_n\in \otimes^n\mathscr{C}^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}), n \le N,$ take $d_n = 0, n > N,$ $(d_n)
  \in \oplus^{lc}_n\otimes^n\mathscr{C}^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ and $(d_n) \in (v_n) + U.$

Construct
$$
    \oplus_n\otimes^n\mathscr{C}^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})
    \to \oplus^{lc}_n\otimes_{sym}^n \mathcal{H}_\tau
    \to \oplus^{Hilb, p}_n\otimes_{sym}^n \mathcal{H}_\tau
  $$
by final property of $\oplus^{lc}$ applied to $\otimes_{sym}^n \mathcal{H}_\tau.$
$\oplus^{Hilb, p}$ is generated by norms $p_n \left\| \cdot \right\|_n$ in each component.
This is continuous map. It has dense image as topology is weakened.

The following map is continuous:
$$
    \oplus_n\otimes^n\mathscr{C}^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})
    \to \widehat{\oplus}^{Hilb, p}_n\otimes_{sym}^n \mathcal{H}_\tau
  $$
($\widehat{\oplus}$ denotes completion) and the image is dense, because the space is dense in its
completion.

By universal property, the following map is also continuous:
$$
    \oplus_n\otimes^n\mathscr{C}^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}) \to \cap_{p, \tau}\widehat{\oplus}^{Hilb,
    p}_n\otimes_{sym}^n \mathcal{H}_\tau
  $$
Sets
\begin{align}
    LH &= \cap_{\tau, p}\widehat{\oplus}^{Hilb, p}_n\otimes_{sym}^n \mathcal{H}_\tau \\
    L &= \cap_{\tau}\oplus^{lc}_n\otimes_{sym}^n \mathcal{H}_\tau
  \end{align}
are equal due to arbitrary $p$ (topologies are different).

Base of topology of $LH$ consists of finite intersections of $\eta^{\prime -1}_{\tau_i,
  p_i}(\Omega_{\tau_i, p_i})$ where $\Omega_{\tau_i, p_i} \subseteq \widehat{\oplus}^{Hilb,
  {p_i}}\otimes_{sym}^n \mathcal{H}_{\tau_i}$ open and
$$
    \eta'_{\tau, q}: LH \to \widehat{\oplus}^{Hilb, q}_n\otimes_{sym}^n \mathcal{H}_\tau
  $$
are canonical (initial topology in category of l.c. topological vector spaces and
in topological vector spaces sets are the same).
As $\eta'_{\tau, q}$ maps to $\oplus^{Hilb, q}_n\otimes_{sym}^n \mathcal{H}_\tau$ and
topology on $\oplus^{Hilb, q}_n\otimes_{sym}^n \mathcal{H}_\tau$ is induced from
completion, one can consider:
$$
    \eta_{\tau, q}: LH \to \oplus^{Hilb, q}_n\otimes_{sym}^n \mathcal{H}_\tau
  $$
and
$$
    LH = \cap_{\tau, p}\widehat{\oplus}^{Hilb, p}_n\otimes_{sym}^n \mathcal{H}_\tau =
    \cap_{\tau,p}\oplus^{Hilb, p}_n\otimes_{sym}^n \mathcal{H}_\tau
  $$
as l.c. topological vector spaces with initial topology induced by maps:
$$
    \eta_{\tau, q}: LH \to \oplus^{Hilb, q}_n\otimes_{sym}^n \mathcal{H}_\tau
  $$

Obtained continuous map:
$$
    \oplus_n\otimes^n\mathscr{C}^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})\to
    \cap_{\tau, p}\oplus^{Hilb, p}_n\otimes_{sym}^n \mathcal{H}_\tau
  $$
with dense image noting that topology is described by finite intersection, see above for
$\eta^{\prime -1}$ and use $\eta^{-1}$ instead.

$\oplus_n\otimes^n\mathscr{C}^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ has dense countable subset by [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154595/is-the-space-of-test-functions-separable?_gl=1*17we9w3*_ga*MTE5NzMzMTA4NC4xNjc1NjMzOTIw*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY5NjI4Nzc1Ni4zNTEuMS4xNjk2Mjg3NzU3LjAuMC4w)

[Yu. M. Berezansky and V. A. Tesko. “The investigation of Bogoliubov functionals by operator
methods of moment problem”] refers to monograph of [Yu. M. Berezansky, Z.  G. Sheftel, G. F. Us,
Functional Analysis, Vols. 2, ch. 14] for the complete proof of the result. It looks like that
monograph is a strong prerequisite to read the paper :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I have one question: I guess you refer by $\oplus_n\otimes^n \mathcal{C}^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ to the space of all linear combinations of products $\psi_1(x_1)\cdot\ldots\cdot \psi_n(x_n)$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$. And how can I use the post you refered to in order to obtain that this space is separable?

Comment: @CoffeeArabica. In each component of the direct sum one takes separable set, finite sums with rational coefficients form countable separable set in the direct sum using description of topology on direct sum. Tensor products are also separable (finite sums of elements like $f\otimes g$).

Comment: Thanks! I agree that we can conclude from the post that $\oplus_n\otimes^n\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ is separable. But for the argument to go through, we would need separability of $\oplus_n\otimes^n C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ where the topology on $\otimes^n C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ is induced by the inclusion into $\otimes^n H_\tau$, correct? Is this space even separable, and if not, how do we conclude the argument?

Comment: @CoffeeArabica We need that $\oplus_n\otimes^n C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ is separable for its own topology and this space has dense image. This implies that the closure of the image in induced topology is separable. Search point $y$ of dense image around given point $x$ in given neighborhood $O$ and then take preimage of $O$ neighborhood in $\oplus_n\otimes^n C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ and find a point $z$ from countable dense subset in this preimage. $z$ would be a point in $O$ around $x.$

Comment: But what is the "own" topology of stated space.

Comment: @CoffeeArabica It is the topology derived from topology of direct limit and inductive topology of $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ for which separability is proven in referenced post. Topology on $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ is different (stronger) from projective topology of intersection, but still it is separable.

Comment: @CoffeeArabica I think that separabitliy of $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})=\bigcap_\tau H_\tau$ in the question (taken as proven) is actually derived from continuous bijective map $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})\to \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}).$ Why did you assume that $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ is separable from the start?

Comment: Yes the separability of $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ is derived by the separability of the inductive limit $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$. I also see why this space is separable itself. But my main problem lies in building a proper tensor product of spaces $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ or $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ with keeping the separability.

Comment: @CoffeeArabica I see. It does not look obvious that "if $A\to B$ is continuous with dense image then $A\otimes A\to B \otimes B$ is continuous with dense image"? This is true for projective topologies on tensor products (Treves "Topological vector spaces, distributions and kernels" 43.9 ($A\hat{\otimes}_\pi A$ is dense in $B\hat{\otimes}_\pi B)$, 43.6). That is $A\otimes_\pi A$ is dense in $B\otimes_\pi B.$

Comment: @CoffeeArabica (cont.) Projective tensor topology is stronger than Hilbert space topology on tensor product (which the topology on $H_\tau\otimes H_\tau$) and both have $B\otimes B$ as dense subsets. It remains to prove that $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})\otimes_\pi C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ is separable. Separability of $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})\otimes_\pi C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ can be proven using definitions of semi-norms for projective topologies, I think.